# How do I fix this parameter error when running game using unity game engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi everyone this is my first Q.

I get this error on the console tab when I run the game.

```
Parameter 'speed' does not exist.
```

UnityEngine.Animator:SetFloat(String, Single)
PlayerMovement:FixedUpdate() (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:30)

Could anyone please help me find the root of the problem please?

Thanks =)

Here is my code

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private float moveHorizontal;
    private float moveVertical;
    private Vector3 movement;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

        movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (movement != Vector3.zero) {
            playerAnimator.SetFloat ("speed", 3f);
        } else {
            playerAnimator.SetFloat ("speed", 0f);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please format your error message, and edit your question to add the relevant parts of your code. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @ThierryLathuille A MCVE isn't possible with Unity in some cases. This case is one of those as animations (and their hookups) cannot be converted meaningfully to a text-based format.

Answer (score 0):

Noob mistake!  "speed" should be capitalized. I should have "Speed", but have typed "speed".

Just incase anyone else has this problem...